# Properly scaling xAxis with time in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Using chart.js, I have a bar chart with datapoints spread across many years:

[image]

If you look closely near the x-axis, you can see some grey bars. Here's a line chart with the same data for reference:

[image]

While using a line chart for this example could make sense, it makes the charts with less data a bit awkward:

[image]

and with bars instead of lines

[image]

Is there an option that could be used on bar charts to improve the readability when large x-axis are involved? I am representing occurrences of events over-time, another adapted kind of chart could be acceptable too.

Thanks.

Comment: If you post your config for your charts, we may be able to provide a better answer. One option would be to expand the `width` of the chart so that there is more breathing room for each date entry.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure there will be an option on chart.js.

One way to deal with it is to render line charts initially and then switch the type to 'bar' when zoomed into certain date ranges.

Depending on the type of data, you could also group up the data by summing (or averaging) the data by day (or week or month). Then pass it into the chart and the time series option should be able to display the x axis dates in a more sensible manner.

Otherwise you will have to look into more power charting libraries that can handle and manipulate bigger datasets like amCharts: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-chart-candlesticks/

Or look into using D3 that is highly customisable, but a bit more complex to work with.